# Class of residually finite groups for which the subgroup lattice is complemented

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm working on a project on quandles, and to this end I want to understand how proofs from group theory relate to quandle proofs. Lots of problems in quandle theory have their group-theoretic analogue, e.g., every subgroup of a free group is free, and the same holds for a free quandle; a free group on $n$ generators is isomorphic to a subgroup of the free group on $2$ generators, and a free quandle can always be realized as a subgroup of a free quandle on $3$ generators.

I want to understand the lattice of subquandles, so I'm looking to the lattice of subgroups for intuition. There is a result in group theory which says that a finite group $G$ is complemented if and only if $G$ is a subgroup of a direct product of groups of *square-free* order.

It seems that there should be a similar result for residually finite groups. A group is residually finite if and only if it can be embedded in a direct product of a family of finite groups. The parallel is clear. My intuition is that there should be some class of residually finite groups for which the lattice of subgroups is complemented, but maybe the result holds for all residually finite groups, I do not know. I am not a group theorist and I do not know many specific results pertaining to this theory. I would like advice for handling this question, unless someone has encountered a positive or negative answer to this question in the past. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Edited, thank you for the advice. I was hoping there would be a quick answer to this problem, but I'm becoming more convinced that an exhaustive affirmative solution would constitute a novel, nontrivial theorem in group theory. Hopefully the edit has added clarity to the situation. If you have further recommendations for meeting users' quality standards, I'd love to entertain your advice : )

Comment: $\Bbb Z$ is not complemented, but embeds into $\prod_p \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$, a direct product of groups of square-free order.

Comment: @LukasHeger You are correct. So evidently not all residually finite groups satisfy this property. Do you have any ideas for an additional condition to residually finite which might make this statement true, in the sense that residually finite + ______ implies complemented?

Comment: @AlexByard I can't think of such a condition.